# How can I use the inventory in Deathspank?

Tags: deathspank

I do not know how to use items that are in my inventory.  I click and pick them up but cannot leave the inventory page with them.  I am at the fountain but can't get the bucket out of inventory?  I am standing near the dish but can't get the can of food from my inventory.  I have a Mac Pro so that you know what controls I am using.  Thanks for any help.

---

It is the bucket for the fountain and the food for the monster that I am having trouble with.  I will try putting them in slots to see if I can get access.  Thank you for taking time to try and help me.  On Mac most everything is click and drag but I cannot drag items from inventory.  I have no problem moving items around on the equipment page in to the correct slots but do not see or have slots in inventory.  I am going to check out the slot suggest.  Thanks again.

Comment: There are quite a few types of "items" in Deathspank. Are these particular items assignable to the item slots (I played on the PS3, where the item slots were assigned to the D-Pad)? Food items fall into this category. If this is the case, try placing the item in one of the item slots and using it that way. Or is it another kind of item, like the tin cans?

Answer (score 1):

Use Command button when standing in front of the well, etc., to use an item. a window will open up with the items to choose from and you then pick the one to use.